# PIM testing in netbeans simulator [J2ME]

Tags: netbeans, java-me, jsr75, java-wireless-toolkit, pim

I am developing an application that works extremely with user mobile phone book in j2me but because the emulator that I use has not any default phone contacts book I can't debug my application (or just see if the application works or not).

I searched a lot but I didn't find any things that can help me.

Is there any possible solution?

Comment: that "netbeans simulator" comes with plenty documentation explaining how to use it to test PIM - User Gude, code examples, sample MIDlets etc - did you check it?

Comment: yes but i didn't find good result.the only thing that i found was a try to make a PIM browser component and then reuse it for real purpose and finally i found that this was goes to hell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the **User Guide** that comes with your emulator. This document is typically available in the installation directory, in sub-folder `docs`.

There is a section related to PIM API. For example, in [Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-wireless-toolkit/info) information you need is provided in chapter 10 *Using the PIM and FileConnection APIs*, section 10.2 *The PIM API*:

> ...emulator stores contact, calendar, and todo information in standard files on your desktop computer’s hard disk. All information is stored in `workdir\appdb\skin\pim`. This directory is shared by all
>   running emulators. Lists are stored in subdirectories of the `contacts`, `events`, and `todo` directories. For example, a contact list called Contacts is contained in:
>
> ```
> ---
> Windows:   workdir\appdb\skin\pim\contacts\Contacts
> Linux:     workdir/appdb/skin/pim/contacts/Contacts
> ---
> ```
>
> Inside the list directory, items are stored in vCard (`.vcs`) or vCalendar (`.vcf`) format (see http://www.imc.org/pdi/). Contacts are stored in vCard format, while calendar and to-do items are both stored in vCalendar format.

Comment: thank you a lot.but emulator don't say anything about how to create vcs files in that directory for testing our application.you know that by default there is only 2 item stored in that directory how to increase them?

Comment: @CoderInNetwork in your your original question there was nothing about creation of vcs files nor items in that directory was it? That would be a **[different question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions "at Stack Exchange sites, “chameleon questions” are not qute welcome")**, consider posting it separately.